# Will hypermeters tuned on sampled dataset work for the whole dataset?

Tags: nlp, bert, text-classification, hyperparameter, huggingface

I'm doing multi-label classification on text data using BERT model. Since the dataset is huge, around  50 thousand rows, I was thinking to use stratify sampling on dataset to reduce it to around 2-4 thousand to hyperparameter tune on.
I'm confused between trading off number of trails with size of sample set. Example: Would training 3000 rows with 5 trials will be better than training 1500 rows with 10 trials?
Moreover, thinking if I should drop epoch from tuning and focus on learning rate and weight decay.